# Angular stepper with multiple sub steps

Tags: angular, angular-material

Angular stepper with multiple sub steps.

```
<mat-step label="Step 1">
////substeps- not in angular material stepper feature
<mat-sub-step><comp1></comp1></mat-sub-step>
<mat-sub-step><comp2></comp2></mat-sub-step>
<mat-sub-step><comp3></comp3></mat-sub-step>
</mat-step>

<mat-step label="Step 2">
  ////substeps- not in angular material stepper feature
<mat-sub-step><comp4></comp4></mat-sub-step>
<mat-sub-step><comp5></comp5></mat-sub-step>

</mat-step>
```

So for step1, user needs to complete 3 pages and for step2 user needs to complete 2 pages form.

But I couldn't find any example or documentation to do that. 
Angular stepper doesn't have something like sub-steps.

In almost all the examples, they are loading one page for one step. but I need to complete multiple components/pages for each step

Comment: Hello, Did you got any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

https://dzone.com/articles/implementing-guard-in-angular-5-app

Tested

#### Practice form validation in my-form page of hello-angular-practice:

1) Create a my-form component using the following commands

```
    ng g component MyForm
```

2) import the my-form and then add the my-form in the Routes of app-routing.module.ts

```
    import {MyFormComponent} from './my-form/my-form.component';

    {path:'my-form', component:MyFormComponent}
```

3) add my-form router link to app.component.html

```
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/my-form">My Form</a>
</li>
```

4) add the below html to my-form.component.html

```
        <div class="container">
          <div class="jumbotron" style="width:50%;" >
            <h2>Form with Validations</h2>
            <form (ngSubmit)="submitForm()" [formGroup]="complexForm">


              <div class="form-group">

                <label>First Name:</label>
                <input id="firstName" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="John" formControlName="firstName">

                <div *ngIf="firstName.errors?.required  && firstName.touched" class="alert alert-danger">You must include a first
                  name.</div>
                  <div *ngIf="firstName.errors?.hasPunctuation" class="alert alert-danger">Name must not have ! or $ characters.</div>

              </div>


              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Last Name</label>
                <input id="lastName" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Doe" formControlName="lastName">
                <div *ngIf="lastName.errors?.required && lastName.touched" class="alert alert-danger">You must include a last
                  name.</div>
                <div *ngIf="lastName.errors?.minlength && lastName.touched" class="alert alert-danger">Your last name must be at
                  least 5 characters long.</div>
                <div *ngIf="lastName.errors?.maxlength && lastName.touched" class="alert alert-danger">Your last name cannot
                  exceed 10 characters.</div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Gender</label>
                <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="!gender.valid && gender.touched">You must select a gender.</div>
              </div>
              <div class="radio">
                <label>
                  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male" formControlName="gender">
                  Male
                </label>
              </div>
              <div class="radio">
                <label>
                  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female" formControlName="gender">
                  Female
                </label>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <fieldset formGroupName="activities">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Activities</label>
                  </div>
                  <label class="checkbox-inline">
                    <input type="checkbox" value="hiking" name="hiking" formControlName="hiking"> Hiking
                  </label>
                  <label class="checkbox-inline">
                    <input type="checkbox" value="swimming" name="swimming" formControlName="swimming"> Swimming
                  </label>
                  <label class="checkbox-inline">
                    <input type="checkbox" value="running" name="running" formControlName="running"> Running
                  </label>
                </fieldset>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="!complexForm.valid">Submit</button>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
```

5) add the below css to my-form.component.css

```
.container {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

6) add the below imports to  my-form.component.ts

```
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators, FormControl, ValidatorFn, ValidationErrors, AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
```

6) inject the formBuilder to constructor of my-form.component.ts

```
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder){
}
```

7) and then add all the below codes inside the my-form.component.ts

```
    complexForm = this.fb.group({
        'firstName' : new FormControl('', [Validators.required,this.hasPunctuation("!"),this.hasPunctuation("$")]),
        'lastName': new FormControl('',  Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2), Validators.maxLength(10)])),
        'gender' : new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
        'activities': this.fb.group({
          'hiking' : [false],
          'running' : [false],
          'swimming' : [false]
        })
    });



    get firstName() {return this.complexForm.get('firstName')}
    get lastName() {return this.complexForm.get('lastName')}
    get gender() {return this.complexForm.get('gender')}
    get activities() {return this.complexForm.get('activities')}



    hasPunctuation(punctuation: string): ValidatorFn{
          return (control:AbstractControl):  {[key: string]: any} | null => {
              return control.value.indexOf(punctuation) >= 0 ?
                   {hasPunctuation: true }: null;
          }
    }

    submitForm(){
        console.log(this.complexForm.value);
        console.log("hiking? "+this.complexForm.get('activities').get('hiking').value);
        console.log("swimming? "+this.complexForm.get('activities').get('swimming').value);
        console.log("running? "+this.complexForm.get('activities').get('running').value);
    }
```

#### Practice angular pipes in hello-angular-practice:

1) To show all the first name of the developers in the bio-component.html, update the dev.firstName like below:

```
<h3><a [routerLink]="['/bio',dev.id]">{{dev.firstName | uppercase}}</a></h3>
```

#### Practice Guard:

1)  Create an auth Guard

```
ng generate guard auth
```

2)  Generate a Login Component and Set it Up

```
ng g component login
```

3) add login.component.ts to route

```
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';

{path:'login', component:LoginComponent}
```

4) add login router link to app.component.html

```
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/login">Login</a>
</li>
```

5) create a login page with below html

```
<div class="container">
  <h1>Login</h1>
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <form (ngSubmit)="login()" [formGroup]="loginForm" >
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="email" placeholder="Email" class="form-control" formControlName="email">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control" formControlName="password">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Login</button>
          </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

6) create auth service

```
ng g service AuthService
```

7) Update the auth.service as below

a) import

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
```

b) inject Router

```
constructor(private myRoute: Router) { }
```

c) add the following fi=unction

```
      sendToken(token: string) {
        localStorage.setItem("LoggedInUser", token)
      }

      getToken() {
        return localStorage.getItem("LoggedInUser")
      }

      isLoggednIn() {
        return this.getToken() !== null;
      }

      logout() {
        localStorage.removeItem("LoggedInUser");
        this.myRoute.navigate(["login"]);
      }
```

8) Now it is time to edit our login.component.ts file.

```
        import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
        import { FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
        import { Router } from '@angular/router';
        import { AuthServiceService } from '../auth-service.service';

        @Component({
          selector: 'app-login',
          templateUrl: './login.component.html',
          styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
        })
        export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

          loginForm;
          constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,
            private myRoute: Router,
            private auth: AuthServiceService) {
            this.loginForm = fb.group({
              email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
              password: ['', Validators.required]
            });

          }

          ngOnInit() {
          }

          login() {
            if (this.loginForm.valid) {
              this.auth.sendToken(this.loginForm.value.email)
              this.myRoute.navigate([""]);
            }

          }
```

9) update auth guard

a) import

```
import { AuthServiceService } from './auth-service.service';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
```

b) update constructor

```
constructor(private auth: AuthServiceService,private myRoute: Router){}
```

c) update canActivate

```
    canActivate(
        next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
        state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
          if(this.auth.isLoggednIn()){
            return true;
          }else{
            this.myRoute.navigate(["login"]);
            return false;
          }

      }
```

10) Do not forget to add AuthService and AuthGuard as providers in app.module.ts.

```
 imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AuthGuard
  ],
```

11) Use Auth Guard in Routes

```
 const routes: Routes =[
  {path:'', component: HomeComponent,canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
  {path:'bio', component: BioComponent,canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
  {path:'bio/:id', component: BioDetailsComponent},
  {path:'create-bio', component:BioCreateComponent,canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
  {path:'my-form', component:MyFormComponent,canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
  {path:'login', component:LoginComponent},

];
```

12) add in app.component.ts

```
import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';
constructor(private auth: AuthService) { }
```

13) update navigation in  app.component.html

```
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-light">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" *ngIf="auth.isLoggednIn()"  routerLink="">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" *ngIf="auth.isLoggednIn()" routerLink="/bio">My Bio</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" *ngIf="auth.isLoggednIn()"  routerLink="/create-bio">Create Bio</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" *ngIf="auth.isLoggednIn()" routerLink="/my-form">My Form</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" *ngIf="!auth.isLoggednIn()" routerLink="/login">Login</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>

        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```